# console.log doesn't make sense when pushing values to array in a for loop

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain what's going on with the output of this code?

```
let arr = [];

for(let i=0; i < 5; i++){
  arr.push(i);
  console.log(arr, i)
}
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] 0
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] 1
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] 2
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] 3
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] 4
```

I'd expect it to look like:

```
[0] 0
[0, 1] 1
[0, 1, 2] 2
[0, 1, 2, 3] 3
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] 4
```

Comment: What console is this, a browser? Some browser consoles save the array pointer, not the contents at the time you log it, so that you can look at the array in the console with the > button

Comment: You can always force the current state to be shown with `JSON.stringify`: `console.log(JSON.stringify(arr), i)`

Comment: Possibly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chrome-s-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-objects

Comment: console.log behaviour is not standardized, and while the call itself should resolve synchrnously, the actualy _data writing_ tends to be asynchronous and non-blocking. So by the time the actual data write happens, the content of your array may no longer be what it was when you called `console.log`. _Always_ console.log `array.slice()` if exact content-at-that-moment matters.

Answer (score 0):

because your console is highly referential (everything in javascript including arrays (-undefined) is object and it is reference)

in chrome devtools 106 this works as expected

you can try a few tricks to create new arrays like:

```js
let arr = [];

for(let i=0; i < 5; i++){
  arr.push(i);
  console.log(arr.slice(0), i)
}
```

> anyway, referencing the output of devtools comes from its own source code with the task execution order. i tried [eruda2](https://npmjs.com/package/eruda2) and it's the same as your devtools